# How to iterate over a list of lists of integers?

Tags: python, list, loops

As far as I know this question hasn't been asked.

If I have two lists like so:

```
a_list = [[1,2], [5,6], [7,8]]
b_list = [3, 4]
```

How can I iterate over them while checking if the values of `b_list` fit the ascending order of the numbers in `a_list`? in this case `b_list` fits between `[1, 2]` and `[5, 6]` and should be appending in that spot. How would this be done in python?

When I use a for loop it tells me:

```
"TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"
```

I used this code:

```
for sub_lst in a_lst:
    for lst in sub_lst:
```

Comment: `subscriptable` refers to the `your_variable[the_brackets_are_subscripts]` syntax.  What are you doing inside these loops?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply append `b` to `a` then sort all elements:

```
>>> a_list = [[1, 2], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
>>> b_list = [3, 4]
>>> sorted(a_list + [b_list])
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: Thanks! But I would like to ensure that it fits with the principal of ensured increasing order. The question isn't so much about appending as it is about checking and ensuring that is the correct position of where b_list should go. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with what you have (with the for loop) do

```py
for index, sub_list in enumerate(a_list):
    if sub_list[0] < b_list[0]:
        continue
    elif sub_list[0] == b_list[0] and sub_list[1] < b_list[1]:
        continue
    else:
        a_list.insert(index, b_list)
        break
```

This will iterate through the list till you get to the right position (takes account of the second spot in case the first one is the same ie [3, 3] and b_list = [3,5]) and append b_list at the index where it stopped

Comment: Thanks! I am new to the whole idea of enumerate. So essentially what it is doing is every time it iterates it puts applies a count to variable index? Because a normal for loop is: for i in a_list. But this one is for i, a_list in enumerate(a_list). The 'i' acts as a count for the index position during every iteration, sort of like if I just put a count var before the loop and iterated it every time inside the loop?

Comment: @Tim_Jarvis99 yup you are right!

Comment: Hey just wanted to reach out, is there any projects you are working on that I could work with you on. I want to build some experience with SD. And your site is amazing.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm very busy and unless you want to do my uni homework I don't think I have the time 

Comment: @Tim_Jarvis99 if you are satisfied with the answer please check the answer (under the vote button)

Answer (score 1):

you could use bisect_left to find the insertion index using a binary search (I'm assuming that there are no range overlaps in your data)

```
a_list = [[1,2], [5,6], [7,8]]
b_list = [3, 4]

from bisect import bisect_left

i = bisect_left(a_list,b_list)
a_list.insert(i,b_list)

print(a_list)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

You can also do it by sequentially searching for the index of the first item that is greater than b_list.

```
a_list = [[1,2], [5,6], [7,8]]
b_list = [3, 4]

i = next((i for i,a in enumerate(a_list) if b_list<a),len(a_list))
a_list.insert(i,b_list)

print(a_list)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```